# How can I submit the input filename into find exec correctly?

Tags: shell, make, latex

I want to create two pdf output files of a single LaTeX source.

One output file is public and the other one (with further information) becomes private.

I use a make file, which uses find to grep the tex file in the directory. This is a simple solution because this way I can reuse the makefile for many projects without needing to modify its content.

This is the important part of the makefile.

```
all:    
        # This creates the public output file
        find -name *.tex -exec sh -c 'pdflatex {}' \;
```

Now I want to add a further line to create the private output file.
It should look something like this:

```
all:    
        # This creates the public output file
        find -name *.tex -exec sh -c 'pdflatex {}' \;
        # This creates the private output file
        find -name *.tex -exec sh -c 'pdflatex --jobname=ABC  '\def\privatflag{}\input{XYZ}' {}' \;
```

For ABC I look for a solution to specify the default filname but with a prefix.

For XYZ I look for a solution to pass the input filename here.

The usage of the inner quotation marks is also not correct here I think.

**Update 1**: Maybe I can explain the problem more simple way.

This command works in the command shell:

```
pdflatex --jobname=outputfile '\def\privatflag{}\input{inputfile.tex}'
```

But I'm looking for a solution to use it with `find -name *.tex -exec` so that I don't need to specify the intput filename inputfile.tex.

Additionally I look for a way that I don't need to specify `--jobname=outputfile`. It should match the input filename with an additional prefix.

**Update 2**: Thanks to [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) and [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas), the issue is solved.

This is now the important part of the makefile

```
all:    
        # This creates the public output file
        find -name *.tex -exec sh -c 'pdflatex {}' \;
        # This creates the private output file
        find . -name '*.tex' -execdir sh -c 'pdflatex --jobname=privat_"$${1##*/}" "\def\privatflag{""}\input{$${1##*/}}"' {}-job {} \;
```

Comment: Did you mean the other becomes private? Also, why `sh -c ...`? Why not just `-exec pdflatex {}` and `-exec pdflatex --jobname=ABC  '\def\privatflag{}\input{XYZ}' {}`? If you ran these commands manually, how would it look, to get an idea of what `ABC` and `XYZ` are.

Comment: The sh -c is not required here, but when I keep it away, it does not help me further solving the issue.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't help. But there's no reason to complicate things when you're trying to troubleshoot an issue.

Comment: Yes. This is true.

Comment: How would the `pdflatex` command be affected by directories? For example, what would you do for `some/path/some/input.tex`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your example, I think what you need is:

```
find . -name '*.tex' -execdir sh -c 'pdflatex --jobname=foo"${1##*/}" "\def\privatflag{""}\input{${1##*/}}"' {}-job {} \;
```

To break it down:

- `-execdir` runs the command in the directory where the file was found.
- `${1##*/}` strips the path from the argument given by `find`.
- The `""` in `{}` is to prevent `find` from replacing `{}` with the matched path.

`sh -c` is need to process the path given by find and extract just the filename.

Comment: Your solution is perfect! It is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Update: The solution works fine on command and in a shell script, but inside a Makefile, the "${1##*/}" part is just ignored. When using it in a Makefile, the output filename is just foo.pdf

Comment: Note that that `{}-job` won't work with all `find` implementations (some will pass that `{}-job` literally (unexpanded)).

Comment: @Neverland, Makefiles have their own variables. You need to write a `$` as `$$` if you want it passed to the shell.

Comment: @ Stéphane Chazelas: Thanks a lot! This caused the error.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are already using a Makefile, you could replace your `find` by make's own mechanisms to handle files, assuming the simple case that your `.tex` files are in the current directory.  For example, this makefile might suffice:

```
ALLTEX = $(wildcard *.tex)
ALLPDF = $(ALLTEX:.tex=.pdf) $(ALLTEX:.tex=.internal.pdf)

%.pdf: %.tex
        pdflatex $<
%.internal.pdf: %.tex
        pdflatex --jobname=$@ '\def\privatflag{}\input{$<}'

all: $(ALLPDF)
```

The variable ALLTEX holds the names of all the input files, and ALLPDF converts these names by replacing the suffix `.tex` by `.pdf` and again by another suffix so you have twice the number of wanted output files.

The next 2 lines setup a rule saying how to generate a pdf file from a tex file, and the following 2 lines setup another rule for how to generate the other suffix. `$<` will be replaced by the input file, and `$@` by the output filename.

Finally, the real target `all:` says it depends on the wanted pdf files. Using make rules has the advantage that a pdf will not be rebuilt if the source tex file has not changed.

Comment: I wonder if OP wants recursion.

Comment: @muru I agree your answer is much simpler and especially so if the `.tex` files are not in the immediate directory. I just wanted to explore other solutions for fun.

Comment: ah, no, I'm not sure my answer is simpler. I think make can be recursive, but I haven't used it much, so I don't know how. And I am too lazy to look it up at the moment. But given the features that make provides, just running find is... ugly.